# Quais as vantagens do PDO::FETCH_OBJ?

Tags: php, pdo

Quais as vantagens de se utilizar PDO::FETCH_OBJ? Sei que me retorna um objeto invés de um array, mas quais as vantagens de desempenho do código?

Comment: Pra responder com certeza, s[o com um benchmark. Mas objetos são mais eficazes que arrays, isso é fato.

Comment: Cara não sei te falar precisamente qual é o mais eficiente. Más não acredito que a diferença no desempenho deles, seja tão significativo assim. A diferença está mais no padrão de projeto que você vai adotar.

Comment: Talvez você tenha confundido FETCH_OBJ com FETCH_CLASS. FETCH_CLASS sim tem algo a ver com Design Patterns pois permite a você enviar os dados diretamente para uma classe Row/Rowset parte de um DAO/ActiveRecord

Comment: Provavelmente não exista alguma vantagem real de desempenho sobre sua aplicação, utilizar objetos invés de arrays está mais para estética do projeto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASSOC, BOTH e OBJ resultam na mesma chamada interna de código, pelo que, a diferença apenas pode ser encontrada no que é retornado.

A resposta mais simplista será indicar que "Não existe qualquer diferença de performance", no entanto eu, assim não considero.

Primeiro e mais importante o numero de campos, certo que é tido em mente que apenas se deve retornar o que é absolutamente necessário. Dito isto e para a mesma quantidade de informação...

O PDO::FETCH_LAZY que está associado a este mecanismo força a criação de objectos e suas propriedades de acordo com a necessidade de acesso às mesmas e aí então podemos avaliar perdas reais de performance. Isto significa que apenas podemos falar de performance quando se acede efectivamente às propriedades e não ao realizar de um fetch().

Diria... se o retorno tiver uma "enorme" quantidade de campos será preferível forçar ASSOC, no entanto e para um pequeno número de campos a diferença será irrisória que não representa algo que seja digno de atenção.